# whats the best way to represent types without id in prisma?

Tags: graphql, prisma

datamodel.graphql

```
type Data {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  points:[Point!]!
}

type Point {
 x:Float!
 y:Float!
}
```

generated types(prisma.graphql) :

```
type Data implements Node {
  id: ID!
  points(where: PointWhereInput, orderBy: PointOrderByInput, skip: Int, after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): [Point!]
}
```

in my datamodel `points` is required field but in generated prisma types `points` is optional ? and when i update points of my Data previous data also coming in result(https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1657) ..

workaround i see is `Json` but we loose type safety in codegen and graphiql :( ,

does prisma going to handle `type` without `id` fields as Json by default in implementation ...?